# UIPickerView: Get row value while spinning?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I'd like to get the row value in real-time as the iPhone user spins a wheel in a UIPickerView (not just when the wheel settles onto a particular row). I looked into subclassing UIPickerView then overriding the mouseDown method, but I couldn't get this to work. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps try implementing the delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

You could treat it as a passthrough (just passing back the reusingView parameter) but each time it was called you would know that view was coming on the screen as the user scrolled - then you could calculate how many views offset from this one the center view was.

Comment: Even easier: in that method, call - (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component, and you'll get the current row and can retrieve its value without calculating offsets or worrying about which way the picker is spinning.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIPickerView` dimensions are fairly consistent. Instead of subclassing it, perhaps you could overlay a `UIView` of your own on top of the picker view, from which you can track and measure dragging motions, before passing those touches down to the picker view.

Comment: Except that then you'd have to reverse engineer the amount of spinning that took place for any given drag, after you had let go...

Comment: I'm not sure that issue would be any different with the subclassing approach. At least with the `UIView` approach, its code could be reused more easily for other purposes.

Comment: True, any approach that looked only at input to the picker view would have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can find UIScrollView in UIPickerView hierarchy by the following method:

```
func findScrollView(view:UIView) -> UIScrollView? {
    if view is UIScrollView {
        return view as? UIScrollView
    }
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if subview is UIView {
            let result = findScrollView(subview as UIView)
            if result != nil {
                return result
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Implement and setup UIScrollViewDelegate:

```
let scrollView = findScrollView(pickerView)
if scrollView != nil {
    scrollView!.delegate = self
}
```

And detect current selected item:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let index = Int(offset/itemHeight)
    if index >= 0 && index < items.count {
        let item = items[index]
        // do something with item
    }
}
```