# UIPickerViewModel.GetView in MonoTouch - how to use it?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get hold of the current 'middle' row as a UIPickerView is spinning. I am trying out the technique from this question here: [UIPickerView: Get row value while spinning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510998/uipickerview-get-row-value-while-spinning)

However, I'm not really sure how to use this override in MonoTouch - I can't call the base, as it's not implemented, and I the fourth parameter (UIView) is always null. Any ideas?

```
public override UIView GetView(UIPickerView picker, int row, int component, UIView view)
{
    // now what to return?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can never call the "base" method in [Model] classes.   This is why you get a descriptive exception that says "Do not call the base method".

All you have to do is not call the base method :-)

Return the last view parameter that is passes as the method return value.

Comment: Thanks, but the last view parameter is null (from my question:  "the fourth parameter (UIView) is always null.")

Answer (score 0):

I found this code that Miguel wrote that answers the question.  Posted for future reference: http://primates.ximian.com/~miguel/tmp/monocatalog/pickercustom.cs