# Get selected row of UIDatePicker while spinning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` in a view whose controller is in a `UINavigationController`. I'm registering changes in the selected date like this:

```
[self.datePicker addTarget:self.alarm action:@selector(timeChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

It works well, except if the user presses the back button in the `UINavigationController` before the date picker has completely settled. In that case, the `timeChanged:` method isn't being called, and so I'm not getting the new date.

Nothing is being released when I press the back button, it's just that the view controller is being popped off. (A reference to it is maintained).

I've found solutions to this problem with `UIPickerView` that involve implementing delegate methods for the picker view (eg: [UIPickerView: Get row value while spinning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510998/uipickerview-get-row-value-while-spinning)). But unless I'm very mistaken, that's not an option with a `UIDatePicker`. If possible, I'd like to stick with the `UIDatePicker` rather than a custom `UIPickerView`. Is there a way to do this? It doesn't have to get the selected row perfectly (within a row or two is fine), but the closer the better.

EDIT: This is for a jailbreak app, so private APIs are fine, if I can figure out what they are.

Comment: This is not possible using public API.  Please [file an enhancement request](https://bugreporter.apple.com) requesting this ability.

Answer (score 3):

As for the current APIs, there's no way of detecting whether a `UIDatePicker` is spinning.

This is because `UIDatePicker` is not a subclass of `UIPickerView` and it manages a `UIPickerView` internally.

I'm afraid the best solution here is to use a custom `UIPickerView`.

Comment: I should say that this is for a jailbreak app, so I can use private APIs if I can figure out what they are. Apple does it in the stock alarm app, so it must be possible, right?

Comment: Of course is possible, since as I said they're using a `UIPickerView` internally. You can try to access the inner picker view by reflection on the `UIDatePicker` object, but I don't know precisely how.