# UIPickerView: Get row value while spinning. how to?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, spinning

As others already asked, I need to read the row value while spinning.

The row values represent a "image frame" number and I need to switch to the corresponding frame while spinning.

It looks like in the question "[UIPickerView: Get row value while spinning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510998/uipickerview-get-row-value-while-spinning)" users Kendall Helmstetter Gelner and user183266 have found a solution.

Please, could you share some more light on that, I'm still a newbie and I could not get to the point. Which are the objects / properties I should use to get the needed values?

Addendum as requested:

As a newbie I could not try much.
Just found out that my rewrite of the delegate method "viewForRow" (and "titleForRow", also) tells me the value of the row coming into the UIPickerView not the value in the center.

After reading Kendall answer in the post I linked above, I tried to see what / where I had to target / get the "views offset" and the "center view".

I know that the delegate "viewForRow" could be the point where to do it, as Kendall suggested, but, I don't know how since I don't understand what he means with "views offset" and "center view".

Comment: Ok, this is what he meant. The method he proposed is called whenever a new view is coming into the screen as you are scrolling. (if view1-view2-view3 are on screen and view4 was offscreen then view4 will be the one that is passed to that reusingView parameter.) Then based on how many views there are in screen in the picker you can calculate which of the views would be in the middle based on the offset. And then you can use this to do your work with. (I guess you can get other views the same way, or just use the view that is coming onscreen). Do you get what he says now?

Comment: That helps. Thanks. But how do I know how many views are on screen? Is there a specific method?

Comment: That depends on how large your UIPickerView is and how large the rows are. You define both of them yourself so I cannot say. Although there are probably defaults and those you can read in the UIPickerView section of the AppleDocs.

Comment: I see. But that only applies to IOS 6, at least in the simulator. That's why I couldn't get it, in IOS 7, my default OS compile version, it behaves much differently. I cannot understand the behaviour in IOS 7, at first, indeed it shows the next coming row but after that it shows the row that is about to enter the center (that is center-1 or center+1). I'm puzzled.

Comment: Could you post what you have done in the titleforrow and viewforrow methods? Also are you trying to make it an infinite/looping spinner?

Comment: Just an NSLog to see when and how viewForRow is called. Right when viewing the uiPickerView starting at row 0, it is called in this sequence: 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1. Then when I slowly spin up to row 3 (selected) it triggers row 2, 1, 5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 3, 7. Spinning back to row 0 triggers this: 1, 2, 0, 1, 0. titleForRow is not called if I also define viewForRow. If I only define titleForRow, it behaves exactly the same way.

Comment: What does the didSelect method say when you log that? It's supposed to give you the view that is under the selection indicator (which should be in the middle, right?) --- Also how are you starting the scroll? Maybe you can instead of the normal scroll make an automated scroll yourself. And scroll in steps of a single row so that you can control which row is in the middle at any given point, given the start position. I wrote a post about this earlier in a UITableView, and it should be similar to a UIPickerView situation.

Comment: PS: no infinite looping spinner. Yepp, didSelectRow shows the correct row: 3 at the first spin and 0 at the second. Yes, I saw some posts about putting UITableView on top of a UIPickerView (addSubview). I think I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. But controlling how to scroll is maybe the best solution to that. And of course you can also determine an endpoint. I don't think I made it stop in my post, but that's a minor detail. If it can go infinite, it can definitely go finite.