# Is it possible to animate a UIPickerView and a UITableview simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

So currently I have UITableViewController that contains both a UITableView and an UIPickerView. The user can select how to filter the data in the table by using the picker. Currently, when the user scrolls over a row in the picker, the table is updated, this is how I accomplished this:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

  // Code to update table data...

  self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
  self.tableView.endUpdates()
  return title
}
```

Unfortunately, the table does not animate when reloadSections() is called. My guess is that this is because I can't animate scrolling the picker and reloading the table at the same time.

How would I go about animating both at the same time? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I think it could work fine.
I was using a snippet like this once, too and it didn't work either. As I recall I solved it by dragging an outlet of the UITableView to the ViewController and then calling

```
 @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView?

    ...


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

  // Code to update table data...

  self.myTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
  self.myTableView.endUpdates()
  return title
}
```

...since self.tableView does not explicitly reference the UITableView you want it to reference. To check if it actually does - have you tried replacing

```
self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

with

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

?

Even if it possibly won't solve your problem, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this did not solve the issue for me. I tried your replacement to test if it was referencing correctly, it does. 

The reason why I think it might be because of the animations is because if I put the reloadSections() in didSelectRow, it animates correctly. In didSelectRow, the user has stopped scrolling, and there aren't any animations going on in the picker.

Comment: Ah yeah I overlooked this part... As you mentioned, the titleForRow (or similiars) function only gets called to "initialize" a cell or when the cell is about to be displayed.
So now you want to update your tableView whilst the UIPickerView is in animation / "spinning" ? Then check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1511347/5743350

Comment: Yes you're correct, I want to update the table while the picker is spinning. I'll try out the solution in the link, thanks! Can I ask where you find the details about the lifecycle of classes? You seem to know more than I can get out of the docs. How did you know that titleForRow only gets called to initialize a cell?

Comment: So did it work yet? 
Well I didn't read about it but sometimes at debugging I added prints to certain functions (just like titleForRow) and then it turned out they're only called when they're initialized or about to be displayed (again). Just try it out :) 
Another approach I was just thinking about is adding a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to either the tableView or the pickerView and then applying the swipe both to the tv and pv simultaneously to make them scroll at the same time? 
Looking forward to hearing from your results!